# 'ListItem' does not contain a definition for 'SystemUpdate' and no accessible extension method 'SystemUpdate'

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have the following CSOM code inside a console application:-

```
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem listItem2 = riskValue.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
listItem2["Title"] = s;
listItem2.SystemUpdate();
```

but i am not sure why i can not access the SystemUpdate method, where i am getting this error:-

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State


Error   CS1061  'ListItem' does not contain a definition for 'SystemUpdate' and no accessible extension method 'SystemUpdate' accepting a first argument of type 'ListItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SystemUpdate` was not present in CSOM until an update in 2016 (if I remember correctly). Make sure you're using the last version of the CSOM libraries, and not an old DLL you may have copied/pasted over years without updates.